# How to add a widget recursively to Flutter layout

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to call a widget inside the other, recursively, I tried to illustrate what I want to do in the image below.
Does anyone know how I can do this?
Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.
[image]

```
Widget createScreen() {
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          TextButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              foregroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _i++;
              });
            },
            child: const Text('Buttom +'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _i--;
              });
            },
            child: const Text('Buttom -'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      ListView.builder(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _i,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: Colors.blueGrey[500],
            height: 100,
            // child: createScreen(), //here I tried to call the function inside itself 
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more snippet, Also it would easier if you just use model widget,

Comment: https://github.com/lucasbarretoluz/RecursivelyWidget I uploaded the project to this git where you can see the whole code. I tried to show what I want to do by creating several different Widgets, but I would like to use just one Widget.

Comment: I want to create a maximum of 5 sublevels

Comment: how about using loop on that case

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Container of a Container of a Container, but at some point, you must not have a further one.  Are you considering what your stopping point will be, and under what condition?  I don't think so, based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've included some logic,but it would be better using model data and having item widget.

```dart
class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyTabbedPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage> {
  int _i = 0;
  int _i2 = 0;
  int _i3 = 0;
  late double heightScreen, widthScreen;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    heightScreen =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    widthScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Teste view")), body: createScreen());
  }

  Widget mainScreen() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: (10),
          bottom: (10),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[350],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          boxShadow: const [
            BoxShadow(color: Color(4293454064), spreadRadius: 1.5),
          ],
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ExpandablePanel(
                header: const Text("Only teste"),
                collapsed: Column(
                  children: const [Text("Test Sub title")],
                ),
                expanded: createScreen(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget createScreen() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  foregroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _i++;
                    if (_i > 4) _i = 5;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Buttom +'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _i--;
                    if (_i < 0) _i = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Buttom -'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _i,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
              return Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  color: Colors.blueGrey[500],
                  // height: 100,
                  child: createScreen2(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget createScreen2() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  foregroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _i2++;
                    if (_i2 > 5) _i2 = 5;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Buttom +'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _i2--;
                    if (_i2 < 0) _i2 = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Buttom -'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _i2,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
              return Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  color: Colors.red[500],
                  // height: 100,
                  child: createScreen3(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget createScreen3() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  foregroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _i3++;

                    if (_i3 > 5) _i3 = 5;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Buttom +'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _i3--;
                    if (_i3 < 0) _i3 = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Buttom -'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _i3,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.yellow[500],
                height: 100,
                // child: createScreen(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```